# create only with applescript a new plist in folder "LaunchAgents"

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, operating-system, applescript

I want to write an applescript that can create a .plist-file and move it or copy it to the folder "LaunchAgents".
When I try to do this by Drag and Drop I need to authenticate it - I think this is the problem why my code is not working.

First I tried this:

> do shell script "touch ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com." & "NameOfTheFile" &
>   ".plist"

But this is not working. I don't know why... And I don't get an error.
So I tried this because I thought its because the authentication:

> do shell script "touch ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com." & "NameOfTheFile"
>   & ".plist" user name "MyUsername" password "MyPassword" with
>   administrator privileges

But this is also not working so I thought I do this in the first line of my code:

> do shell script "chmod 777 ~/Library/LaunchAgents" user name
>   "MyUsername" password "MyPassword" with administrator privileges

Also not working! : /

So my question ist:
Are my commands wrong?
Why does it not work?
How can I create a new file in the folder "LaunchDaemon" or "LaunchAgents" only with applescript?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, the property list is simply created as literal text and then written into the directory. Change `Program` and `ProgramArguments` to your values.

```
property pListLabel : "com.myLabel"

set userLibraryPath to path to library folder from user domain as text
set LaunchAgentsFolder to userLibraryPath & "LaunchAgents:"
set pListfile to LaunchAgentsFolder & pListLabel & ".plist"
try
    tell application "Finder" to make new folder at folder userLibraryPath with properties {name:"LaunchAgents"}
end try

set PLIST_data to "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">
<plist version=\"1.0\">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>" & pListLabel & "</string>
    <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/mycommand</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>my</string>
        <string>argument</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
"
try
    set ff to open for access file pListfile with write permission
    write PLIST_data to ff as «class utf8»
    close access ff
on error
    try
        close access file target
    end try
    display dialog pListLabel & " couldn't be created" buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
end try
```

PS: Do not `chmod` folders in `(~)/Library` unless you know exactly what you're doing.